# Resize firefox add-on sdk panel from user

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is is possible firefox add-on SDK panel to be resized from user? 
I have read the documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel
 but not find way how to do this.

Comment: I did this for someone on stackvoerflow  few months ago. I cant remember the topic. I have the stuff raound here somewhere. try searching a bit u'll definitely find it, if not let me know and ill dig it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can resize the panel, using the [resize method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#resize%28width.2C_height%29)

```
let panel = Panel({ /* ... */ });
panel.resize(width, height);
```

Comment: Much better than my way!

Comment: I want the user to be able alone to resize the popup, the same way as dialogues under windows.

Comment: For that way you will have to hack it up. Even giving a panel css resize property won't do the trick. I would say put an element at bottom right, when user mousedowns on it then record the cursor position, on mousemove, calc the offset the new position and old position, then call resize like that.